# C++, определение виртуального деструктора в заголовочном файле

Tags: c++, header, virtual, деструктор

У меня есть вопрос по поводу определения виртуального деструктора в заголовочном файле.

Например, есть заголовочный файл, который содержит:

```
class Object
{
    public:
    virtual ~Object(){}
    // ...
};
```

Я лишь недавно столкнулся с кодом, подобным этому. Прежде, я считал, что любую реализацию нужно писать в `.cpp` файле, чтобы при подключении заголовка в разных единицах трансляции не возникло множественных определений.

Мои вопросы:

1. Действительно ли виртуальный деструктор можно определять в заголовочном файле?
2. Можно ли что-то еще определять в заголовочном файле (речь про методы и функции)?
3. Если что-то и можно определять в заголовочном файле, то должно ли это нечто быть пустым, как в примере с ничего не делающим виртуальным деструктором?
4. В каком `Стандарте` и в каком месте об этом можно почитать?

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: а вы почитайте про работу компилятора и компановщика.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, _компоновщика_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Можно. Любой метод, функцию или переменную можно определять в заголовочном файле, при условии что они являются inline.
2. Любой метод можно определять в заголовочном файле. Делать это можно либо прямо в определении класса (как в вашем примере), либо после определения класса с указанием ключевого слова `inline`.
3. Нет, не должно.
4. В любом стандарте С++ почитать про спецификатор `inline`, его связь с Правилом Одного Определения (ODR), inline-функции и способы определения методов класса как inline.

   Тема inline-переменных появляется в С++17.

Единственной тонкостью тут является то, что если вы захотите объявить некий метод класса как pure virtual, но при этом еще и предоставить для него определение, то это определение должно находиться за пределами определения класса.

Answer (score 4):

> Действительно ли виртуальный деструктор можно определять в заголовочном файле?

Да, это можно сделать in-place, как в Вашем примере, можно вынести определение за пределы объявления класса, и, наконец, можно пометить деструктор как *default*:

1. `inline Object::~Object() {}`
2. `virtual ~Object() = default;`

> Можно ли что-то еще определять в заголовочном файле (речь про методы и функции)?

Да, можно.

> Если что-то и можно определять в заголовочном файле, то должно ли это нечто быть пустым, как в примере с ничего не делающим виртуальным деструктором?

Нет, не должно.

> В каком Стандарте и в каком месте об этом можно почитать?

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_definition
2. http://eel.is/c++draft////dcl.fct.def

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки.

Comment: @MGNeo, не за что. Рад помочь!